# Jquery validation + ajax + php + without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been suffering from a solution of a problem for days.
I would like to use jquery validation and ajax call without page refresh together.
If I only use one of them, the code is working properly but together not. I would like a very simple, comprehensible code.

Could you help me where the problem can be? Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Atti

```
**teszt.php**
<!doctype html>
<html lang="hu">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#form').validate({
            rules: {
                nev: {
                  required: true,
                  minlength: 2
                }
            },
            messages: {
                nev: {
                  required: "We need your email address to contact you",
                  minlength: 2
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $('#button_id').click(function(){
                    var nev=$("#nev").val();
                    var action=$("#action").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "php.php",
                        data: "nev="+nev+"&action="+action,
                        success:function(result){
                            $("#nevem").html(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
                form.submit();          
            }
        });
    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="nev" name="nev">
<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="addadd">
<input type="button" id="button_id" name="button_id" value="Mentés">
</form>
<div id="nevem"></div>

</body>
</html>

**php.php**
<?php 

if ($_POST["action"] == "addadd") {

echo $_POST["nev"];
} else {
    echo 987;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it as such:

```
$('#button_id').click(function(){
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
  rules: {
            nev: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 2
            }
        },
        messages: {
            nev: {
              required: "We need your email address to contact you",
              minlength: 2
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {

                var nev=$("#nev").val();
                var action=$("#action").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "php.php",
                    data: "nev="+nev+"&action="+action,
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#nevem").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
}); 
}); // no .submit() here
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it is still not working :(
php.php file is not called by ajax.

Comment: Just saw that your click binder is in the wrong place. Try the update

Comment: I copied your solution above into the code, modified the html form id="myform", too.
If the click binder is the first, even the validation is not executing.

Comment: I'm doing this on a phone currently. Have a look when I have a laptop to test

Comment: Could you check it on notebook?